# Pandas: sum all rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
score num_participants
0     20
1     15
2     5
3     10
4     12
5     15
```

I need to find the number of participants with `score` that is greater than or equal to the `score` in the current row:

```
score  num_participants  num_participants_with_score_greater_or_equal
0      20               77
1      15               57
2      5                42
3      10               37
4      12               27
5      15               15
```

So, I am trying to sum current row and all rows below it. The data has around 5000 rows, so I can't manually set it by indexing. `cumsum` doesn't do the trick and I am not sure if there is a simple way to do this. I have spent quite some time trying to solve this, so any  help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a reverse `cumsum`.  Reverse the list, `cumsum`, then reverse back.

```
df.iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]

   score  num_participants
0     15                77
1     15                57
2     14                42
3     12                37
4      9                27
5      5                15
```

Comment: `iloc` is preferred to `ix` these days for positional indexing because of `ix`'s hard-to-explain semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `score` is already sorted, how about

```
df['num_participants_with_score_greater_or_equal'] = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False).num_participants.cumsum()
```

to make `score` is in the right order. You can restore the original order by `.sort_index()` after.

Comment: Misunderstood your point about 'need to find the participants with score lower...'.